# Greasemonkey disable script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I need to disable this line on my webpage via Chrome greasemonkey/tampermoney extension:

```
$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=initgapi");
gtag('config', 'UA-4163888-28');
gtag('config', 'AW-1066657416');
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read';
gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: '660406747714.apps.googleusercontent.com', scope: scopes, state: appstate, response_type: 'code', redirect_uri: 'https://membri.mysite.com/bodies/oauth2.asp', immediate: false });return false;
```

Each of the lines are within various script lines.

Anyone can help to achieve that ? I have tried to do it myself but fail.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.mysit.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


 (function() {
'use strict';

var adSidebar = document.getElementById('getScript');
if (adSidebar) {
adSidebar.parentNode.removeChild(adSidebar);
} 

})();

$('.validation_ticker').remove();oauth2.asp
```

Comment: `I have tried to do it myself but fail` show what you've tried, because what you've shown is not really enough to help

Comment: I have updated the question.